# Android.FirebaseUI-Android: We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Android Studio 2.3.3

I use FirebaseUI-Android for auth by phone number. It's work fine.
I do many tests and after some days I get the next error:

**we have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity**

And now I can't auth and can't test my application.

So how I can turn off this? And as result to test again my application by **FirebaseUI-Android**?
I need to create many tests for auth of my application.

Comment: have you created any user in Firebase console?

Comment: Yes, I have Firebase console

Answer (score 2):

Follow this steps

Go to your

```
Firebase console -> Auth -> Users table
Locate the user you are testing.
Delete this user.
Retest.
```

This solution works for me .